# Combine Google Analytics with external data

Tags: sql, google-analytics, etl

I need to merge my GA statistics with external data (stored in SQL but I can expose them by some web service). Perfectly all the data should be available in GA for reporting but I found no solution for import the data into GA.

Do you know any piece of software that can do this and present the merged results in some readable form to the user? It should meet the following requirements:

1. Should be a web application
2. Should not be a software-as-a-service solution (will be hosted in infrastructure provided by me)
3. Should provide some level of automation in data import

[Analytics Canvas](http://www.analyticscanvas.com) looks interesting but I wonder if there are any other applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics allows you [import data through the API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtDataImport) and manually through the Web Interface. For example this is a very good article on [integrating external CRM user data](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/data-import-user) with Google Analytics. But Google analytics also support importing the following types of data:

- Product Data
- Refund Data
- Cost Data
- Content Data
- User Data

You can also create your own custom dimensions and metrics and import that data into Google Analytics and view the results in your own custom reports.

Answer (score 3):

Analytics Canvas is indeed a good option, it has really good data extraction and transformation capabilities, and handles nicely any data out of both SQL data sources and the most recent GA API.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I saw it is an desktop application. Do you know if it has some web based extension/app version that would meet the rest my requirements?